# Can't take off armor (not cursed!)

Tags: nethack

For some reason I cannot take off my blessed +1 ring mail I started the game with. It just says "You can't take that off". I found a better piece of armor that provides a better AC and is much lighter and I would very much like to equip it. What's causing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may be wearing something over top of that armor that would prevent it from being removed, such as a cloak.

Comment: Wearing *any* cloak, regardless of BUC status, prevents you from removing body armor. You must remove the cloak first.

Comment: Using `Shift-A`, you can remove armor out from underneath cloaks without taking off the cloak first. I can't remember whether this is classified as a bug or not, though.

Comment: @MikeyB: Oh wow. I never even thought of that. The dev team really does think of everything. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeyB How does this factor in with cursed cloaks?

Comment: If you have a cursed item over a non-cursed item I believe you have to deal with the curse before you can remove the items under it. (at least as I recall from playing Nethack over the years)

Comment: Using `Shift-A` does not allow you to bypass a cursed cloak to remove your armor.